# Getting Wavlink (Displaylink) USB-VGA adaptor to work on Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, usb, xorg

Complete noob when it comes to Linux here, so any help would be much appreciated.

I have a Wavlink UG39DH4 USB adaptor that I'm trying to get working on a headless Ubuntu Server (22.4.1).

I'm currently accessing the server via a console (serial) interface and can perform basic tasks like driver installation... etc.

I have followed the guides to install the drivers for the device, which appears to have completed successfully, and the device does show up when I issue the "lsusb" command as "Displaylink USB Display Adaptor". However, I can't get it to display anything.

I've installed the "ubuntu-desktop" but when I try to do "startx", I get the "(EE) no screen found" error.

Sometimes when I disconnect/reconnect the screen from the Adaptor, a message along the lines of: usb 1-3: device not accepting address 8, error -71" shows up.

A bit lost as to what to try next...

Thanks in advance for any help you can throw my way.

Cheers,

red